# How to Add a border around a State In leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet

I am working with this example of US map `http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html.`
I am Highlighting the map of a state using a color. But the problem is there are some markers that were clickable before the addition of this highlighting color now becomes non clickable. How can I make the markers clickable even after keeping the map highlighted? Any solution? By the way I am using the following code to highlight the map:

```
function getColor(d) {
     if(d === "Iowa")
         return '#800026';
     else
         return '#ffffff';
       }

function style(feature) {
  return {
    //fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.name),
    weight: 4,
    opacity: .1,
    color: getColor(feature.properties.name),
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.3
};
}


L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have the `fillColor` option commented out. If you remove the `//` before `fillColor` it should work.

Comment: If I remove the comment out option. The same thing happens. Just the fill color appears